# Flutter: Agora chat setup. Error code 100, appkey is invalid

Tags: flutter, chat, agora.io

I am trying to use the chat feature provided by Agora. But on sign in, the console is logging an error code of 100 for appkey is invalid.

[image: qalaqand]

I followed exactly as mentioned in the example provided by Agora, [Agora Docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Need fill in the info below in [quick_start/lib/main.dart file](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=flutter#implement-peer-to-peer-messaging)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:agora_chat_sdk/agora_chat_sdk.dart';

// Replaces <#Your app key#>, <#Your created user#>, and <#User Token#> and with your own App Key, user ID, and user token generated in Agora Console.
class AgoraChatConfig {
  static const String appKey = "<#Your app key#>";
  static const String userId = "<#Your created user#>";
  static const String agoraToken = "<#User Token#>";
}
```

Comment: I have this code as well. But it still throws the above-mentioned error, "invalid appkey".

Comment: try reinstall app

Comment: I deleted the app and reinstalled it again and it worked! Thank you for the help!

Comment: i am new , there is no online reference to use agora chat except docs which is cluttered. can you share some guide or resource son how to use agora-chat .currently i am using agora-rtm for messaging but i want to convert my code to use agora chat.

Comment: @VeerPratap The documentation has got some gaps of information, my team and I solved the problem by contacting the support team. They will direct you to a proper solution.